# How do I dump yaml without evaluating anchor values?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file as

```
anchor1: &anchor1
  resource_class: small

anchor2: &anchor2
  hello: world

anchor3: &anchor3
  hello: world

root1:
  nested1:
    <<: *anchor1
    some_list:
      - item1:
          hello: world
      - *anchor2
      - *anchor3

  nested2:
    <<: *anchor1
    some_list:
      - item1:
          hello: world
      - *anchor2
      - *anchor3

  nested3:
    <<: *anchor1
    some_list:
      - item1:
          hello: world
      - *anchor2
      - *anchor3


root2:
  nested1:
    <<: *anchor1
    some_list:
      - item1:
          hello: world2
      - *anchor2
      - *anchor3

...
```

I want to pull out the value of `nested1` into a separate file without evaluating all the anchors.

```
import ruamel.yaml.YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open(Path('in_file')) as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

with open(Path('out_file'), 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data['root1']['nested1'], f)
```

The output I want when dumping is

```
<<: *anchor1
some_list:
  - item1:
      hello: world
  - *anchor2
  - *anchor3
```

I understand it is invalid yaml, as the anchor definitions are not present.

The main problem I run into, is that the moment I grab a value from the root config, it has already been processed.

For example, if I load and dump my `in_file`, it works as expected, but if I take the data and get a value out, `data['root1']`, it has already processed the anchors.

I suspect that's because the anchor definitions are not part of `data['root1']` but I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: In what situation would you need such a YAML segment?

Comment: I'm breaking up a large ( 1600 lines ) Circle config file into folders and files for organization. I will then merge it as needed. https://circleci.com/docs/how-to-use-the-circleci-local-cli/#packing-a-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with files containing YAML documents, use the [officially recommended
extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for such files, which
has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Then you should consider using `pathlib.Path()` instances for files when loading
instead of providing a stream:

```
data = yaml.load(Path('in_file.yaml')
```

resp. dumping:

```
yaml.dump(data, Path('out_file.yaml')
```

(although that output might be considered not to be a file containing a YAML document).
*Your original use of `yaml.dump()` is not going to work as you opened the file for reading only, and your
updated version opens the output for 'w', but `yaml.dump()` dumps an (UTF-8) binary stream (so use 'wb')*

---

Although it is possible to hook into the representer to skip output until a certain point,
it is much more easy to do the selection post-processing using the `transform` parameter
of the `dump` method:

```py
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

in_file = Path('in_file.yaml')
out_file = Path('out_file.yaml')

class SelectKey:
    """this assumes mappings for all levels of keys, mappings indented by indent spaces"""
    def __init__(self, *keys, indent=2):
        self.keys = keys
        self.indent = indent

    def __call__(self, s):
        """
        s will contain the full YAML output, process it line by line to find key
        """
        processing = [False] * len(self.keys)
        result = ""
        level = 0
        for line in s.splitlines(True):
            dedented_line = line[level*self.indent:]
            if processing[level]:
                if not line.startswith(' ' * (self.indent * level)):
                    break
                dedented_line = dedented_line[self.indent:]  # the values
                if line and line[0] not in ' \n':
                    break
                result += dedented_line
            else:
                key = self.keys[level]
                if dedented_line.startswith(key) and dedented_line[len(key)] in ' :':
                     processing[level] = True
                     if level + 1 == len(self.keys):
                         pass  # we don't want the key itself, only its value
                     else:
                         level += 1
        return result.rstrip() + '\n' # remove potential empty lines
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(in_file)
yaml.dump(data, out_file, transform=SelectKey('root1', 'nested1'))
print(out_file.read_text(), end='')
```

which gives:

```
<<: *anchor1
some_list:
  - item1:
      hello: world
  - *anchor2
  - *anchor3
```

You need to call `yaml.indent()` to get your non-standard sequence indentation. As
the selection is based on the "path" of keys to a value, you won't get
just any value for a key `nested1`.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Sorry about the bad file handling. I'm using Path internally. I wrote that part quickly ( and made mistakes ) here to get the point across.

I'll try this and get back. Thank you!

Comment: So, this didn't work for me. It works when working with the entire file and if I want to get the value of a root key. But if I want to work with nested keys, it's basically like working with a text file at that point ( Something I want to do as a last resort ).

Additionally, if I try to use SelectKey with the value of a root key, it's too late, as the anchors have been processed already.

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect my requirements. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer, but that still involves rather trivial parsing of indented lines in the function passed to `transform`

Comment: That seemed to work! There were minor issues, but I worked around them. The main one was that it was incorrectly breaking out of the loop if it encountered a blank line.
`root1:\n  nested1:\n    - hello\n\n    - world`

It would cut off at `hello`. Not a trivial problem unless you start looking ahead but simple pre-processing to remove unnecessary newlines fixed that.

I also had to change `if not line.startswith(' ' * (self.indent * level))` to use `dedented_line.startswith...`

But it works great now. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really test for empty lines within a value, (the `if line and line[0] not in ' \n'` was supposed to cope with that from the original answer). I am not sure if your change of `line.startswith....` always works correctly, but you probably have more test cases than I do, that check that.